# Redirect to url based on server or system time

Tags: redirect, time, fixed, counting, seconds

I am searching for a way to redirect to a url based on fixed time when the time (system or server) hits 06:00 o'clock it needs to redirect to given url.. it needs to check the time (system or server) every second i dont know if this is possible..?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using javascript. I made an example. This checks the current hour and if it is between start and end it does something. you could trigger timeRedirect(); at document load or something.

```
<script>
        function returnTime() {
            var d = new Date();
            var time = d.getHours();
            console.log(time);
            return time;
        }

        function timeRedirect() {
            var start = 6;
            var end = 22;
            var time = returnTime();

            if (time >= start && time <= end) {
                console.log("redirect");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and for the redirect you could use this javascript, place it where the console.log(redirect) is.

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: cant use it because the page does not refresh or load in the mean time.. it has an index showing some things, but on 18:00 o'clock it needs to redirect to show a black page with a clock.

Comment: I found something that looks like what i want only without the dropdown and form elements.. http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/alarm.shtml